# Dynamically change on condition of SQL Inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, case

I need to write a sql query for the following scenario. if b.field1 = 123 then my query should have inner join ON condition like this.

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on (a.field1 = b.field1 or a.field1='abc' or  field1='def')
where b.field1 = 123 and a.field2 = 'W'.
```

if b.field1 value anything other than 123, then my query should have diff inner join ON condition.

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on (a.field1 = b.field1)
where b.field1 = 234 and a.field2 = 'W'.
```

Basically based on the b.field1, i need to have different ON condition for the inner join. I dont want to write 2 queries. I tried using case, but was having hard time implementing it, getting syntax errors.
Can somebody with SQL expertise advice me how can i write this in 1 query.

I tried something like this, but I'm having 2 issues, IN is not allowed when using case and also in the THEN & ELSE part of CASE, it is allowing me to use any one of the fields selected(**a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3**).

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on a.field1 in 
case when b.field1 <> 123
then 
 (b.field1)
else
 (b.field1, 'abc', 'def')
end
where b.field1 = 123 and a.field2 = 'W'.
```

I'm posting answer as it might help somebody.

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on ((b.field1 <> 123 and a.field1=b.field1) 
or (b.field1=123 and a.field1 in (b.field1, 'abc', 'def')))
where b.field1 = 123 and a.field2 = 'W'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the second part of the first `JOIN` condition (`or a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def'`) to the first part (`a.field1 = b.field1`), conditioned by `b.field1 = 123` i.e.

```
inner join b on (a.field1 = b.field1 or b.field1 = 123 and (a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def'))
```

Comment: I already tried this before posting my query here. This condition will consider a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def' even when b.field1=234. I want query ON condition to consider only (a.field1 = b.field1) when b.field1 = 234 and when it is b.field1 = 123, then consider other part too **a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def'**. This is the reason I was asking about case statement inside inner join ON condition.

Comment: @Matt this won't consider `a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def'` when `b.field1=234` because `a.field1 != b.field1`

Comment: Finally I solved like with below query.select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on a.field1 on ((b.field1 != 123 and a.field1=b.field1) or 
(b.field1 = 123 and a.field1 in (b.field1, 'abc', 'def')))
where b.field1 = 123 and a.field2 = 'W'.

Comment: @Matt the logic of what you just wrote can be simplified down to what I wrote, `b != 123 & a = b | b = 123 & (a = b | a = 'abc' | a = 'def')` => `b != 123 & a = b | b = 123 & a = b | b = 123 & (a = 'abc' | a = 'def')` => `a = b & (b != 123 | b = 123) | b = 123 & (a = 'abc' | a = 'def')` => `a = b |  b = 123 & (a = 'abc' | a = 'def')`

Answer (score 1):

You can typically rewrite any sort of if/conditional logic with careful use of AND, though performance can take hit in the process.

```
ON (b.field1 = 123 AND (first conditions))
OR (b.field1 <> 123 AND (second conditions))
```

As said above, the performance can take a hit (MySQL performance, index utilization in particular, is relatively poor when OR is involved); so an alternative is to use a UNION (which is still a single query, even if more verbose and semi-redundant):

```
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on (a.field1 = b.field1 or a.field1='abc' or a.field1='def')
where b.field1 = 123 and a.field2 = 'W'
UNION ALL
select a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, b.field1, b.field2, b.field3
from a
inner join b on (a.field1 = b.field1)
where b.field1 = 234 and a.field2 = 'W'.
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know if performing a `UNION` was more efficient than adding one `OR` to the `JOIN` clause...

Comment: @Nick It often can result in much better performance even with simpler conditions; my most memorable was a query of the form `... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.from_a_id OR a.id = b.to_a_id ...` _(this assumes indexes that can be taken advanage of are present in the first place)_

Comment: Union will not work. I need to get data for either 123 or 345 not both at a time.

Comment: I was under the impression you were attempting to avoid having to execute two queries; if your actual query is that dependent on the already known value of the parameter, and not some attribute of other data associated with it, I'd just recommend keeping both queries separate and only executing the one you actually need. Writing two separate queries, or dynamically construction one based on input, is often better than trying to make a "swiss army knife" query when such a query is not needed.